# Fastest way to loop thru a SQL Query

Tags: sql

What is the fastest way to loop thru a Query in T-SQL .
1) Cursors or 
2) Temp tables with Key added or 
any thing else.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am getting some data from a query and want to loop thru the 1st to last item and do a string concatenation of a field in the result set.

Comment: Basic rule of thumb: avoid cursors whenever possible - they're dead-slow, clumsy, and just not suited for T-SQL. Use a set-based approach instead - load it into a temp table and run a UPDATE statement on it.

Comment: ECLARE @numbers VARCHAR(255)

SELECT @numbers = COALESCE(@numbers + ' | ','') + PHONE_NUMB FROM my_table (NOLOCK)
WHERE CONTACT_ID=@contact_id   RETURN @numbers

How do I add a Case statement Example say If my phone number format is International , add international Pin etc. Just as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a cursor for that (your comment about concat) if I understand what you're going for.
Here's one of mine that grabs all the phone numbers for a contact and plops them in a field and returns it.

```
DECLARE @numbers VARCHAR(255)

SELECT @numbers = COALESCE(@numbers + ' | ','') + PHONE_NUMB FROM my_table (NOLOCK)
WHERE CONTACT_ID=@contact_id   RETURN @numbers
```

Comment: How do I add a Case statement 
Example say If my phone number format is International , add international Pin etc. Just as an example.

Comment: It's just normal SQL. You can use typical query syntax.

DECLARE @RET VARCHAR (4192)
SELECT @RET = COALESCE(@RET + ' | ', '') + 
LTRIM(COALESCE(
 CONTACT_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + CONTACT_LAST_NAME,
 CONTACT_REF,
 CONTACT_COMP_NAME) 
+ ISNULL(' ' + CONTACT_SSN,'')
)

FROM my_table WHERE my_conditions
RETURN @RET

Comment: How do I use a CASE Statement in here .IS it possible?

Comment: here's another example.

DECLARE @RET VARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @RET = COALESCE(@RET + ' | ', '') + 
CASE WHEN PHONE_TYPE_ID=1 THEN 'HOME'
ELSE 'OTHER' END
+ ' ' + PHONE_NUMB
FROM 
my_table
WHERE CONTACT_ID=@CONTACT_ID
RETURN @RET

Comment: I don't. Post your query please.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to "loop" thru a query is to just not do it.  In SQL, you should be thinking set-based instead of loop-based.  You should probably evaluate your query, ask why you need to loop, and look for ways to do it as a set.

With that said, using the FAST_FORWARD option on your cursors will help speed things along.

Answer (score 3):

For your stated goal, something like this is actually a better bet - avoids the "looping" issue entirely.

```
declare @table table
(
    ID int
)

insert into @table select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5

declare @concat varchar(256)

-- Add comma if it is not the first item in the list
select @concat = isnull(@concat + ', ', '') + ltrim(rtrim(str(ID))) from @table order by ID desc

-- or do whatever you want with the concatenated value now...
print @concat
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're trying to do. Some tasks are better suited for cursors, some for temp tables. That's why they both exist.

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are usually resource hogs especially as your table size grows.  So if your table size is small I would be okay with recommending a cursor, however, a larger table would probably do better with an external or temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to loop through query output inside stored procedure OR from C# code?

Generally speaking, you should avoid looping through query output one row at a time. SQL is meant for set based operations so see if you can solve your problem using set based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your result set - Table variables are in memory and require no disk read, can be treated just like a table (set operations) and are very fast until result set gets to large for memory (which then requires swap file writes).

Comment: table variables can live in tempdb as well - http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/03/30/sql-server-table-variable-vs-local-temporary-table.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shortcut to get a comma-delimited string of a single field from a query that returns a number of rows. Pretty quick compared to the alternatives of cursors, etc., and it can be part of a subquery (i.e., get some things, and in one column, the ids of all the things related to each thing in some other table):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
        (SELECT MyField AS 'c' FROM [mytable] FOR XML PATH('')),'</c><c>',','), 
          '<c>',''),
        '</c>',''),
      '')
   AS MyFieldCSV
```

Caveat: it won't play nice if your column contains characters that FOR XML PATH will escape.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor is not good avoid cursor and use while loop in place of cursor
Temp table with key added is the best way to use looping.

i have to manipulate more than 1000000 rows in the table and
for cursor take 2 min because of complex logic.
but when convert cursor in to while loop it will take 
25 seconds only. so that's big diffrence in performace.