# Speeading up query by removing cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have query that looks like this

```
 declare @tmpTable Table(id int)
 insert into @tmpTable(id) values (3)
 insert into @tmpTable(id) values (5)
 insert into @tmpTable(id) values (11)

 declare @tmp int
 declare @finalString varchar(MAX)

 DECLARE c1 CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR SELECT ID FROM @tmpTable
 OPEN c1
 FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @tmp
 set @finalString=cast(@tmp as varchar)
 FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @tmp
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 begin
  set @finalString=@finalString+','+cast(@tmp as varchar)
  FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @tmp
 end    
 close c1
 deallocate c1  

 select @finalString
```

I want to create string formated this way "3,5,11" from table column values, this code works, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Several ways. Suggest you search SO...

Comment: e.g. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071022/fastest-way-to-loop-thru-a-sql-query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019942/concatenating-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - use this method (`STUFF` combined with `FOR XML PATH` ):

```
SELECT
   STUFF((SELECT ','+CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10))
          FROM @tmpTable    
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Returns an output of:

```
3,5,11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE or xquery.

```
CTE:
with t1(rowNum, id) as
(
    select rowNum, id from Temp1
),
t2(rowNum, str) as
(
    select 1, cast(id as varchar(250)) from t1 where rowNum=1
    union all
    select t1.rowNum, str || ',' || cast(t1.id as varchar(3)) from t1,t2
    where t2.rowNum+1 = t1.rowNum
)
select str from t2 order by rownum desc FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```